# Non-EU citizen Schengen visa via NYC Swiss embassy

Tags: visas, schengen

I am applying for Schengen visa via Switzerland embassy in NYC.

One of their requirements is :

> A copy of your confirmed flight reservation.

How do I purchase temporary tickets to meet this requirement?

Comment: You can get a fully refundable ticket directly from the airline's website. These tickets are generally much higher than the lowest priced option.

Comment: You can also reserve the flight without paying for it.

Comment: @Michael.. where?

Comment: The refundable ticket is the safest strategy to get the visa issued. Be careful of bogus reservations, they know about them too.

Comment: @SMV from a travel agent (does anyone remember what those are?).

Answer (score 3):

Most airlines offer fully or partially refundable tickets, which you can choose to buy if you're unsure whether you'll get the visa or not. Note that they're typically more expensive than economy type seats and that airlines don't refund tickets on the basis of a visa refusal. Also, beware of sites or services that offer to "rent" airline tickets for visa purposes as visa agencies are usually aware of them.